# Binary "star" operator

Tags: notation

I'm in the process of implementing a decoder, and I found this formula in the official specification:

[image]

In context, X and Y can be interpreted as either two integers, or two arrays of integers (byte arrays).  But I have no idea what the binary "star" operator means.

At first I thought it was just multiplication, but that makes no sense in context.  So, I Googled around for some other mathematical uses of this star/asterisk operator, and found it can be used to mean "[free product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product)", but that seems to pertain to group theory and it's hard to see how `40` can be interpreted as a group.

So what is this operator? (The document where I found the operator is http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf section 8.19.4)

Comment: Why doesn't multiplication make sense in this context?

Comment: The document uses an `X` symbol to mean multiplication elsewhere, and if it is multiplication there's no need for those parentheses.  Also, I can't see how multiplication would produce a sensible result

Comment: Why would it not produce a sensible result? If $X$ is an integer $X*40$ would be the integer obtained by multiplying $X$ by $40$. If $X$ were an array, $X*40$ would be the array obtained by multiplying each entry by $40$.

Comment: Elementwise multiplication makes sense in this case. This is also the notation, that is used in Matlab. In mahematics the symbol $*$ means usually convolution, but it isn't applicable now.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the note,

> NOTE – This packing of the first two object identifier components recognizes that only three values are allocated from the root
>   node, and at most 39 subsequent values from nodes reached by X = 0 and X = 1.

... makes it very clear $X,Y$ are integers and that $*$ is meant to denote multiplication here. Multiplication here 'separates' the two adequately; essentially this is the same idea as 'packing' two single-digit numbers into a two-digit one.